# How to disable input field but show tekst with hook_form_alter?

Tags: 8, hooks

In D8 I have a form with several fields.
One specific field is a number. Input widget is Integer.

This field is prevalued with hook_form_alter like:

```
$nid     = \Drupal::request()->query->get("source"); // query string param
$node    = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
$pe_punten = $node->get('field_pe_punten')->value;
```

I would like to achieve that the user has no access but can see this value. To disable it I can do:

```
$form['field_pe_punten']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

But how to replace this input widget with a piece of text which says "10 points"

I red several other QA but could not find out how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `#disabled` like below:

```
$form['field_pe_punten']['#disabled'] = 'disabled';
```

Comment: Great never knew this property